# sorting excel rows based on the values of a column using Java

Tags: java, excel

I am generating an excel using my java program . I want  that excel file to be sorted based on the values of a column . The type of these values is String

can anyone help?

Comment: Can you not sort your data before exporting to Excel instead?

Comment: no, because I am printing row by row

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, you are generating excel like CSV file, then you can do sort the row on based of the value of a column

First,

Create a java class that holds the column values as an object, then stored these objects into a *List* collection.

Then create a custom *Comparator* to sort that *List* collection and write list object into excel file.